# How might I obtain an IShellFolder from the active IShellView?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, windows-shell

I'm trying to enhance a CFileDialog, and we're using the older version of it (the non-vista one that doesn't use IFileDialog).  The older one does allow me to obtain an IShellBrowser, as well as (from that) the active IShellView.

What I cannot seem to come up with is a way to get "What IShellFolder does that IShellView refer to?"

Equally useful would be "What is the current folder that IShellBrowser has made active?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have solved it in a round about fashion: I'm using CDM_GETFOLDERIDLIST, which returns the current PIDL, which is all I need.  :D