# Can an IShellFolder be retrieved from an IShellView?

Tags: shell, winapi, com

If I wanted to filter using `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject` instead of filling in my own `IResults`, how could I get the `IShellFolder` from the `IShellView` passed to `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject()` so the `PIDL` name could be retrieved relative to the folder instead of having to use something like `SHGetPathFromIDList` or `SHGetPathFromIDListEx` ?

TIA!!

Comment: Your question is strange (plus what's IResults?). You aren't implementing ICommDlgBrowser, are you? In general, only Windows Shell stuff (Explorer, Common Dialogs) implements this. Usually the IShellFolder creates the IShellView so it's kinda the other way around. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Filter using `ICommDlgBrowser::IncludeObject` is for implementation of  `ICommDlgBrowser`.   It provides the `IShellView` and `PIDL`, I'd rather get the name from the `IShellFolder` than from `SHGetPathFromIDList()`.  `IResults` is where you can custom fill the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I obtain an IShellFolder from the active IShellView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247567/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau looks like a dupe to me

Comment: @JonathanPotter Sort of. Both this and the related question are badly named. The question title is generic and applies to all hosted shell views but they are both really interested in the Open/Save dialog but failed to include that in the title.

Comment: You can try 1) ShellView.QueryInterface(IFolderView) 2) FolderView.GetFolder(IShellFolder)